# Virtual Button Vuforia scripting

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, virtual, augmented-reality, vuforia

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class fullscreen : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
{

    private GameObject vbButtonObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        vbButtonObject = GameObject.Find("fullb");
        vbButtonObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterEventHandler(this);
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
    }
    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("2");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

This is my codes for a project when I try VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour instead of VirtualButtonBehaviour it's underlining it like there is a typo. My virtual button not working please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the AR camera is on the image target It works for me !!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNfyX.png)

Comment: The problem not about even working or not it's about scripting

Comment: give me your console image